# Trying to enable WIFI on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, wifi

The OS is as follows:

```shellsession
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

In the past I used wired connection from the router through the ethernet port with no issue.

This host has two network (ethernet) cards and I use one through network switch for LAN. Hence I can access the host. Now I only have Vodafone 5G Mobile Hotspot which only has WIFI. So I need to configure for WIFI. I also added a [USB Wifi Dongle](https://www.amazon.co.uk/600Mbps-Adapter-Computer-Internet-Desktop-Black/dp/B09Y1NSBC7/ref=asc_df_B09Y1NSBC7/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=606937433920&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11622204083081810336&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9045903&hvtargid=pla-1882209699532&psc=1&mcid=af702f1824c935e2beb52bb27c896c2b) as below

```
[  260.653316] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811
[  260.653318] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  260.653319] usb 1-5: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[  260.653320] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  260.653321] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 123456
```

However, I cannot see any WiFi reference below

```shellsession
$ nmcli dev

DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
enp9s0           ethernet  connected     enp9s0
br-ce0756fca55e  bridge    connected     br-ce0756fca55e
docker0          bridge    connected     docker0
virbr0           bridge    connected     virbr0
enp0s31f6        ethernet  disconnected  --
enp5s0           ethernet  disconnected  --
lo               loopback  unmanaged     --
virbr0-nic       tun       unmanaged     --
    
$ cat /proc/net/wireless
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
```

Login through console and looking under WiFi is telling me "NO WIFI Adapter found"

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

From the `idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811`, this is apparently a [Realtek RTL8811CU](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0bda/c811) chip, whatever is the name it's being marketed as.

You'll need to install a driver for it, here:
https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916